# Commit a single update, inside a transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, commit

I need some help...

this is a sort of Rails 3.0.15 pseudo code to explain my problem:

```
progress_bar = ProgressBar.create

record = Record.new
10000.times.do
  record.bodies.build
  progress_bar.inc
end
record.save
```

the code creates 10000 bodies of record, but they are wrapped inside a transaction, so they are committed at once, and this is fine.

ProgressBar.create a record in a table, and inc should increment a counter, so a js progress bar can read the current count from the table and update the progress, but the ProgressBar update, triggered by inc, is  trapped inside the Record transaction, and committed with the 10000 records... useless!

Any idea on how to force an update inside a transaction, without committing the entire transaction?

Or what kind of alternative storage can I use to save the progress bar current position?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realtional databases generally cannot do a write while inside a transaction, so your choices are to send a message somehow so another database connection will deal with progress bar, or (and this is a lot easier and better, imo) store your progress bar data in something else like Redis or Memcached; they are designed for this usage.

Comment: SOLVED. Your solution puts me in the correct way. I go for PStore to create an external repository.

Comment: ASAP I'll publish my new gem for solving the Status Bar problem in rails... stay tuned!